# How to run flask server from another module?

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to run a flask server from another module and then close the server (it's not the main point of the application), currently the code looks like this for webserver.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_classful import FlaskView
import os
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from flask import request



host = 'localhost'
debug = True


app = Flask (__name__)
app.config

@app.route('/')

def main(): 
   return render_template("index.html")
def run():
    if __name__ == 'Refactor2': 
        app.run(ssl_context = (r"path_to_cert", r"path_to_key"), host = "localhost", port = 443)

def shutdown_server(): 
    func = request.environ.get('werkzeug.server.shutdown')
    if func is None:
        raise RuntimeError('Not running with the Werkzeug Server')
    func()

def shutdownServer():
   shutdown_server() 
   return "Server is shutting down"
```

I am then trying to run this in the following module (named Refactor2):

```
import webserver 

class buyer:
    def __init__(self, email, password):
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
    
    def server_run(self):
        run()
        print("Server has been started")
```

However, the server does not run and I cannot navigate to the webpage. There are no error messages shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like an unusual way to launch a Flask app, but with that aside...

Assuming you're running this with `python Refactor2.py`, `__name__` will be `'webserver'`.

This can be demonstrated with a minimal example:

```
$ cat webserver.py 
def run():
    print (__name__)

$ cat Refactor2.py 
import webserver
webserver.run()

$ python Refactor2.py 
webserver
```

So in your `webserver` module you could do do:

```
def run():
    if __name__ == 'webserver':
        app.run(ssl_context = (r"path_to_cert", r"path_to_key"), host = "localhost", port = 443)
```

Or just:

```
def run():
    app.run(ssl_context = (r"path_to_cert", r"path_to_key"), host = "localhost", port = 443)
```

And call it like:

```
import webserver
# ...
class buyer:
    # ...
    def server_run(self):
        webserver.run()
        print("Server has been started")
```

Of course, that 'Server has been started' won't actually be reached until the server (the `webserver.run` call) has completed and the server has stopped.

Again, this seems like an odd way to launch an application.  I suggest you investigate the docs on how to run Flask in production, as it seems what you're trying to acheive is the job of an orchestration system, and not the python process itself.  In a production env, you should use a WSGI server like gunicorn, instead of the dev server (`app.run`).  Granted, perhaps you know this already ;)

Answer (score 0):

`__name__` gives the name of the current module.  So in your `run()` method `__name__` is probably resolving to `webserver`. I'd suggest passing the name as a variable to `run()` from `server_run()`

webserver.py

```
def run(name):
    if name == 'Refactor2':
        app.run(ssl_context = (r"path_to_cert", r"path_to_key"), host = "localhost", port = 443)
```

Refactor2

```
import webserver 

class buyer:
    def __init__(self, email, password):
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
    
    def server_run(self):
        run(__name__)
        print("Server has been started")
```

Note that if Refactor2 is in a package you might get a dotted module name, like 'src.Refactor2'.  It might be better to pass a more explicit name to run, as if you rename Refactor2 you'll need to update your hardcode in webserver.py too.  Something like

```
def server_run(self):
        webserver.run('buyer')
        print("Server has been started")
```

and

(webserver.py)

```
def run(name):
    if name == 'buyer':
        app.run(ssl_context = (r"path_to_cert", r"path_to_key"), host = "localhost", port = 443)
```

edit: not sure if you provided a full code example, but it also looks like maybe you're not calling the right `run()` method in `server_run()` - it looks like it should be called on the webserver module, which I edited my answer to reflect